# Correct way to calculate two durations from a single duration and ratio

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have implemented a method to calculate on and off times periodic behaviour, using a period given by `std::chrono::duration` value and a duty cycle `float`. This is shown in the code block below. The value of duration and duty cycle are supplied only at run time, so I think use of std::ratio is out of the question. Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to implement this?

```
PeriodicPulse(const Period period, const float duty): mRunning(false)
{
    if (duty < 0 || duty > 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Duty value should be between 0-1.");
    }
    auto tempTime = std::chrono::duration<float, decltype(period)::period>(period.count() * duty);
    mOnTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<decltype(mOnTime)>(tempTime);
    tempTime = std::chrono::duration<float, decltype(period)::period>(period.count() * (1 - duty));
    mOffTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<decltype(mOffTime)>(tempTime);
}
```

Comment: Does your code not work? what's the problem with on and off time you get? Also better make sure `duty > 0` as well.

Comment: There is functionally, nothing wrong with this - at least in my testing thus far. This code works. I am just curious as to whether there is a 'better' way to do this. Thanks , yes I should - too many beers!

Comment: That's opinion based. Personally I think your code is fine and 'proper'. If you really want feedback better move this to stack `codereview`, which is better suited IMO.

Comment: Noted - I was hoping that Howard Hinnant would pick up the thread and point out any improvements

Comment: Ahh :) maybe try and catch him in a chat.

Comment: Howard had a much-deserved late sleep this morning... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, especially if your tests are showing that it is doing what you want.  Below I offer a few stylistic cleanups, and I've put the constructor within the context of `PeriodicPulse`:

```
struct PeriodicPulse
{
    using Duration = std::chrono::milliseconds;

    bool mRunning;
    Duration mOnTime;
    Duration mOffTime;

    template <class Rep, class Period>
    PeriodicPulse(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> period, const float duty)
        : mRunning(false)
    {
        if (duty < 0 || duty > 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Duty value should be between 0-1.");
        }
        using namespace std::chrono;
        duration<float, Period> tempTime = period * duty;
        mOnTime = duration_cast<Duration>(tempTime);
        tempTime = period * (1 - duty);
        mOffTime = duration_cast<Duration>(tempTime);
    }
};
```

- I've renamed `Period` to `std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>` to indicate it is actually expected to have type duration, but with the variable name `period` to describe the functionality of the time duration.  This also serves to constrain (what I have assumed) is an overly generic template parameter.  (my assumption may be incorrect)
- When in function scope I find repeated use of `std::chrono::` overly verbose and hard to read.  I prefer a function-local `using namespace std::chrono;`.  You may feel differently.
- I replaced:

---

```
auto tempTime = std::chrono::duration<float, decltype(period)::period>(period.count() * duty);
```

with:

```
duration<float, Period> tempTime = period * duty;
```

---

This reuses `Period` from the rewritten parameter type, and avoids the unnecessary use of the `.count()` member function.

- For the assignment of `mOnTime` and `mOffTime` I've created a `Duration` alias so that I don't have to say `decltype(mOnTime)`.  There's nothing wrong with `decltype(mOnTime)`, I just find `Duration` a little more readable in this context, and I can still change the type of these members in a single place.
- `duration_cast` isn't necessary when giving `tempTime` its second value as there is an implicit conversion to floating-point-based durations.  And I've again avoided the `.count()` member function so as to stay within the type-safety protection of the `<chrono>` type system.

I tested it out like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using P = duration<int, ratio<1, 30>>;
    PeriodicPulse p{P{3}, .2};
    cout << p.mOnTime << '\n';
    cout << p.mOffTime << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
20ms
80ms
```

which is the same answer I get with your original code.

The use of [`"date/date.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) isn't necessary. This is just me being lazy in streaming out `p.mOnTime` and `p.mOffTime`.